# How do I change the name of the folder GRUB installs to?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have two partitions and one is meant to be solely for GRUB2's files. The layout of the filesystem on the first partition should look like:

```
/
     fonts/
     i386-pc/
     locale/
     grub.cfg
     grubenv
```

This is what I expect to get when I run `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`. Instead, I get this:

```
/
    grub/
        fonts/
        i386-pc/
        locale/
        grub.cfg
        grubenv
```

Why is it placing them in another sub-directory? I did not specify `/mnt/grub` and I have seen GRUB get installed to folders like `/boot/grub2`, so I know that it doesn't always make a folder named `grub`. How do I force it to do what I want it to do?

Comment: According to `man grub-install`, it always creates the subfolder `grub`...

Comment: @ByteCommander It may say that, but I have seen instances where it uses a different directory. On openSUSE it uses `grub2`.

Comment: Maybe they use a different version or modification of GRUB over there? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the directory that concerns you only at build time, by passing a value to `--with-grubdir=` at configure time:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/configure.ac?h=grub-2.02#n280
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-install.c?h=grub-2.02#n339
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-install.c?h=grub-2.02#n251